# Setting up Dask worker with variable

Tags: dask

I would like to distribute a larger object (or load from disk) when a worker loads and put it into a global variable (such as `calib_data`). Does that work with dask workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the client method [register_worker_callbacks](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.register_worker_callbacks) can do what you want in this case. You will still need *somewhere* to put your variable, since in python there is no truly global scope. That somewhere could be any attribute of an imported module, for example, which, then, any worker would have access to. You could also add it as an attribute of the worker instance itself, but I see no obvious reason to want to do that.

One way which works, hijacking a randomly picked builtin module; but I do not particularly recommend this (see below)

```
def attach_var(name, value):
    import re
    re.__setattr__(name, value)

client.run(attach_var, 'x', 1)

def use_var():
    # any function running on a worker can do this, via delayed or
    # whatever method you pass with
    import re
    return re.x

client.run(use_var)
```

Before going ahead, though, have you already considered `delayed(calib_data)` or `scatter`, which will copy your variable to where its needed, e.g.,

```
futures = client.scatter(calib_data, broadcast=True)
```

or indeed loading the data in the workers using ordinary `delayed` semantics

```
dcalib = dask.delayed(load_calib_data)()
work = dask.delayed(process_stuff)(dataset1, dcalib)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. I come from the ipyparallel world where you could just say workers['x'] = 5 and then there would be a global `x` which is 5 on all workers. I currently have done this:
```def init_workers(atom_data):
    globals()['ATOM_DATA'] = atom_data```

and then do client.run(init_workers) - maybe that is not what we want. what do you think @mdurant

Comment: I'm not certain you want to copy ipyparallel's approach, the delayed/futures way is much more explicit. Also, I'm not certain that attaching to globals will work (you can try), since any function you pass will have a different closure of globals. I would attach to a module.

Comment: seemingly, I don't quite understand dasks purpose and how it differs from ipyparallel and joblib and the rest. I have 40k parametersets that I need to put through a python/Cython/C - hybrid  that is openmped. I want each worker to run one task at the same time on a slurm/torque/sge kind of setup. I'm happy to ask this question as a proper stackoverflow question

Comment: I think you better had. I believe the answer above is sufficient for the question as posed. (Note that you can use Dask as a backend for joblib, including "scattering" a variable to all tasks)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469195/dask-joblib-ipyparallel-and-other-schedulers - let me know if this is clear or should be improved.